# A pattern to parse links in a text

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have some texts that may contain links like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a> sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

I want to find links (`a` tags) inside this text, what is the regex pattern for that?

This pattern doesn't work:

```
const string UrlPattern = @"(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?";
var urlMatches = Regex.Matches(text, UrlPattern);
```

thanks

Comment: A regex that would parse any and all `<a>` tags would be a huge unmaintainable monstrosity of a black box. Is that the one you want?

Comment: Would you consider using another solution than a regex, for example the HtmlAgilityPack ? If so you may avoid many pains at a later time

Comment: It's a text that contain just `a` tags. not HTML

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's exactly the same as example above in question.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272): please link to answer, not to non-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML (its available from NuGet):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
               .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Result:

```
[
  "http://loremipsum.net/",
  "http://loremipsum.net/"
]
```

Suggested reading: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: My name is samy, and i approve this answer

Comment: @samy my name is Sergey, and I say thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe so

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"<a.+?href=(['|""])(.+?)\1");
resultString = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups[2].Value;
```

for list of matches

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"<a.+?href=(['|""])(.+?)\1");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[2].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Can you add more description?

Comment: change code - use regexp ( select url from href attribute of a tag)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XML parser which is much more robust and reliable in this kind of task. But if you want something *very* quick and *very* dirty, here it is:

```
<a.*?<\/a>
```

If this is too simple, and you need to capture the link address or the link content, go with this:

```
<a.*?href="(?<address>.*?)".*?>(?<content>.*?)<\/a>
```

They both don't match correctly nested tags.